# how to add a subtotal rows in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i want to add subtotal in between the rows

for example
this the rows and column
NOTE : these three column i am fetching from maintable

```
a   b   c
a1  100 100
a2  200 200
a3  300 300
a4  400 400
a5  500 500
a6  600 600
a7  700 700
a8  800 800
a9  900 900 
a10 900 900
```

i want like this

```
a                      b    c
a1                    100  100
a2                    200  200
a3                    300  300
a4                    400  400
subtotal(a1 to a4)    1000 1000
a5                    500  500
a6                    600  600
subtotal(a5 to a6)    1100 1100
a7                    700  700
subtotal(a7)          700  700
a8                    800  800
a9                    900  900
a10                   900  900
subtotal(a8 to a10)   2600 2600
Grandtotal            5400 5400

note : grandtotal = addition of subtotals
```

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Comment: But you said "in PL/SQL" which implies a stored procedure. And why did you remove the Oracle tag? PL/SQL for stored procedures is only available in Oracle.

Comment: i added oracle tag, i justwant query ... i will create stored procedure by using that query

Comment: When do you want your subtotal? Every 3 rows? (And btw: adding the subtotals / grand total in your reporting tool instead of in SQL would probably be much easier)

Comment: because i already have one big stored procedure , i just want to add these query, so i want query , not a stored procedure

Comment: not every three rows... as mentioned above example fourth row i want and then 7 th row i want and then 8th row i want grand total

Comment: in reporting tool i tried, in that i got subtotal for every row

Comment: What is the reason why you want that subtotal with values (600-600)between a3 and a4? There shouldn't be only one subtotal when when grouping by only one column? What do you really mean?

Comment: sorry for changing the requirement , please help me, actually i want to create a report like this above mentioned example

Comment: but what is the reason that is pushing you to do that subdivision. First time after 4 elements, then after 3, then just for 1, then after 3 again... and what for the remaining million rows? Consider to explain this to get some help!

Comment: this is the example of my report. already i have the report like a b c column , in that only 10 rows wil be appear, it wont change. only value of b and c wil change. just i want to insert the subtotal inbetween that.

Comment: but i want according to that format which i mentioned, that is my client requirment

Comment: You can use the query I provided in my answer and modify subtot_id value to follow your requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to combine the use of rollup and grouping functions in this way:

```
select 
  decode(grouping(a),1,decode(grouping(subtot_id), 1, 'total', 'subtotal'),a) as a,
    sum(b) as b, sum(c) as c
from (
    select trunc((rownum-1)/3) as subtot_id, a, b, c
    from your_table
    order by a
  )
group by rollup(subtot_id, a)
```

I made a sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d23ce/8)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced in Oracle but I came out with this solution. Required types and function needs to be defined for each table you want to work with. It should be used on small tables because of the time of executing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE row_abc
AS OBJECT (
  a varchar2(10),
  b integer,
  c integer
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE table_abc 
AS TABLE OF row_abc;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name(
    report_freq INTEGER := 3
) RETURN table_abc AS
  ret table_abc;
  counter INTEGER := 0;

  CURSOR abc_cursor IS
    SELECT row_abc(a, b, c) FROM main_table;
BEGIN
  ret := table_abc();

  OPEN abc_cursor;
  LOOP
    counter := counter + 1;
    IF counter!=1 AND mod(counter, report_freq)=1 THEN
      ret.extend;
      SELECT row_abc(
        'subtotal',
        (SELECT SUM(b) FROM
          (SELECT b, rownum rn FROM main_table)
          WHERE rn>=counter-report_freq AND rn<counter),
        (SELECT SUM(c) FROM
          (SELECT c, rownum rn FROM main_table)
          WHERE rn>=counter-report_freq AND rn<counter)
      ) INTO ret(ret.count) FROM dual;
    END IF;

    ret.extend;
    FETCH abc_cursor INTO ret(ret.count);
    EXIT WHEN abc_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE abc_cursor;

  counter := counter - 1;
  IF mod(counter, report_freq) != 0 THEN
    SELECT row_abc(
      'subtotal',
      (SELECT SUM(b) FROM
        (SELECT b, rownum rn FROM main_table)
        WHERE rn>counter-mod(counter, report_freq) AND rn <=counter),
      (SELECT SUM(c) FROM
        (SELECT c, rownum rn FROM main_table)
        WHERE rn>counter-mod(counter, report_freq)AND rn <=counter)
    ) INTO ret(ret.count) FROM dual;

    ret.extend;
  END IF;

  SELECT row_abc(
    'grandtotal',
    (SELECT SUM(b) FROM TABLE(ret) WHERE a='subtotal'),
    (SELECT SUM(c) FROM TABLE(ret) WHERE a='subtotal')
  ) INTO ret(ret.count) FROM dual;

  RETURN ret;
END function_name;
```

And you execute it in sql with following line to get your requested output

```
SELECT * FROM table(function_name(report_freq));
```

where `report_freq` is value of frequency of subtotal reports.